# Interrupting Threads that are blocked, waiting for input from a Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

When a Thread is interrupted while it's also blocking on input from a Socket's `InputStream`, do the resources of that Socket (e.g. the local port) get released?

I know the Socket has an option called `SoTimeout`. If I set the `SoTimeout` option, does the port that the Socket is bound to get released when the timeout expires?

Comment: depends on what your code does when you catch the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is nothing that says that `Thread.interrupt()` will interrupt the read *at all,* let alone close the socket, *unless* it is an `InterruptibleChannel`, in which case the semantics are clearly documented that a `ClosedByInterruptException` is thrown and the channel is closed.
2. If you set a socket timeout and get a `SocketTimeoutException`, the socket remains open. None of its resources are released (including it's port), meaning that you cannot bind a new Socket to that port until the Socket is closed.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout itself will neither close the Socket, nor unbind the port. You need to call `socket.close()` to accomplish that.